# Error in repository view Redmin ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8)

Tags: git, repository, redmine

I configured several month Redmin to see GIT repositories (on same server), since few days when i try to show repositories page i have an error 500 , i could not anymore see in a ticket the commit (with #ticket numero). the error is:

```
Rendered repositories/_navigation.html.erb (17.6ms)
  Rendered repositories/show.html.erb within layouts/base (22.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 401ms (ActiveRecord: 9.1ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT     and UTF-8):
27:                    :id => 'tag' %>
28:   <% end -%>
29: 
30:   <% if @repository.supports_all_revisions? %>
31:     | <%= l(:label_revision) %>: 
32:     <%= text_field_tag 'rev', @rev, :size => 8 %>
33:   <% end %>
  app/views/repositories/_navigation.html.erb:30:in `block in     _app_views_repositories__navigation_html_erb__997203925942952170_70174274845000'
  app/views/repositories/_navigation.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_repositories__navigation_html_erb__997203925942952170_70174274845000'
  app/views/repositories/show.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_repositories_show_html_erb___3665620718196763072_70174275009180'
  app/controllers/repositories_controller.rb:125:in `show'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

i have already mysql2 gem in version 0.3.11
i have utf8 configuration

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: redmine
  host: localhost
  username: redmine 
  password: redmine
  encoding: utf8
```

and in environment.rb :

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

i don't know what i can do i know it is a problem of encoding in a comment or in title tag or other on my reprository but while checking in gitlab i did'nt found anything strange.

any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

To make it work i had to change file redmine/lib/redmine/scm/adapters

l89 add this line :

```
bran.force_encoding("UTF-8") if bran.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
```

l102 replace

```
@tags = io.readlines.sort!.map{|t| t.strip}
```

by

```
@tags = io.readlines.sort!.map do |tag|
          tag = tag.strip
          tag.force_encoding("UTF-8") if tag.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
          tag
        end
```

following

Comment: Thanks. Is there any related issue in redmine so we know when it is fixed in upstream?

Comment: i d'ont know for me it works and i think in the past not related in redmine